# How to get more torque using a Stepper motor

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am using a stepper motor with a belt. The system has more friction due to the belt. So, I need to increase the torque of the motor at rotating.
I am currently using [57HS09](http://www.leadshine.com/UploadFile/Down/57HSxxd.pdf) motor and [M542](http://www.leadshine.com/UploadFile/Down/M542d.pdf)
It has microstepping setting as 1000PPR and full current(4.0A) is given.
Pulse generated by an Arduino. The main coding is given bellow.

This is the function of Arduino code.`stepDelay` is given by another function after some calculation.

```
void move() {
  if (micros() - lastStepTime >= stepDelay) {
  lastStepTime = micros();
  digitalWrite(STEP_UP, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  digitalWrite(STEP_UP, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
}
```

}

I have no idea how to increase the torque more.
How do I increase the torque of the stepper motor?

Comment: A belt should not add a significant amount of friction. Perhaps it needs idler pulleys to go around obstacles, or if it is under very high tension then the motor shaft could need support  at the free end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possiblities.

1) You can increase the current in the motor. Your motors are rated for 4 amps. Use it. Be aware that this will increase the self-heating of the motors, and depending on your motor mounts you may overstress the motors. Using wood or plastic is not a good idea. Metal will conduct heat away from the motors much better.

2) Cut the number of microsteps. Using microsteps is a tradeoff of less torque for smoother operation and better resolution. You'll get maximum torque with no microstepping at all.

Comment: Best performance in torque is limit slew rate on step rate to max and 0 velocity with full steps to prevent skipping with Imax.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to increase torque with that controller is by changing current settings using DIP switch 1, 2, 3. See page 5 in the documentation.

Comment: I am using 3.0A RMS settings. 
Can I change the torque changing the micro-stepping?

Comment: As far as I know increasing number of microsteps actually _reduces_ torque. See [here](https://www.micromo.com/media/wysiwyg/Technical-library/Stepper/6_Microstepping%20WP.pdf)